# Using "eject -s /dev/sdx" appears to send more then only the SCSI eject command over USB/MSC connection

Tags: usb, usb-drive, embedded-system, eject, scsi

I am writing embedded STMicro.com STM32 processor code and using the STMicro.com's USB drivers.  There is no other software running on the STM32 processor. It is a bit unusual, but we have managed to configure the STM32 processor to switch from a USB/CDC to a USB/MSC device on command. The problem is to find a way to switch back from USB/MSC to USB/CDC.

To solve this, I believe I can connect the STM32 based device using a USB cable to a Ubuntu computer and send an SCSI Eject command.  However this does not always work.  I find I have to send the SCSI Eject command at least twice.  And, on occasion, as many as 5 times before my STM32 code sees 1 Eject event. Why?

To verify the STM32 code works, I then connected the STM32 based device to a Windows 10 machine.  Using the Eject feature found in the Windows File Explorer, I was able to see every Eject event the Windows 10 machine sent to the STM32 based device. So, it would appear the STM32 code and STMicro.com USB drivers work (with Windows 10).

Going deeper...

I ran the STM32 processor debugger while the STM32 based device was connected to the Ubuntu computer.  While debugging the STMicro.com's USB driver, I observed that all USB/MSC SCSI Eject commands are seen.  However, the driver over writes the eject flag with other USB/MSC states such as LOCK and UNLOCK before my code sees the EJECT state.  Here is that segment of STMicro.com code that can be found a github.com:

```
if ((params[4] & 0x3U) == 0x1U) /* START=1 */
{
hmsc->scsi_medium_state = SCSI_MEDIUM_UNLOCKED;
}
else if ((params[4] & 0x3U) == 0x2U) /* START=0 and LOEJ Load Eject=1 */
{
hmsc->scsi_medium_state = SCSI_MEDIUM_EJECTED;
}
else if ((params[4] & 0x3U) == 0x3U) /* START=1 and LOEJ Load Eject=1 */
{
hmsc->scsi_medium_state = SCSI_MEDIUM_UNLOCKED;
}
else
{
/* .. */
}
```

Is it that Ubuntu sends more then just the SCSI eject commands when the:

```
eject -s /dev/sdx
```

...command is used?  Is there any way to only send the SCSI Eject command over the USB/MSC connection from Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you please provide more information on the question? Are you debugging some external device which you connected to yours via USB and using the manufacturer's driver to interface it? If that is correct, is the device a mobile modem by any chance? That could explain the weird driver behavior. 

If you do provide additional information, please edit it into the question.

Comment: There is only a Win10 or Ubuntu/Linux PC and my STM32 based device that can operate in either USB/CDC or USB/MSC.  My device is only connected to 1 of the computers at a time.  When connected to Win10 I can detect the EJECTION event every time.  When connected to Ubuntu I only see the EJECTION even after it is sent several times.  I realize there is a disconnect between your detailed description and how I asked my question.  I think this is because of the STMicro drivers.  I'll adjust my question to include this information and a github reference to the STMicro code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### eject sends 'ALLOW MEDIUM REMOVAL' and then 'START STOP' SCSI commands to eject the device.

I've looked over the [eject's source code](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/eject.c).
What happens during 'eject -s' is the invocation of eject_scsi function, during which the following happens:

1. Struct sg_io_hdr_t, which is used to send the SCSI commands, is
   defined.
2. SCSI command '**ALLOW_MEDIUM_REMOVAL**' (allowRmBlk) is issued.
3. If allowRmBlk succeeded, SCSI command '**START_STOP**' (startStop1Blk)
   is issued.
4. If succeeded, SCSI command '**START_STOP**' (startStop2Blk) is issued again with different options.

allowRmBlk, startStop1Blk and startStop2Blk are what is used in the actual source code, but I have also shown the actual commands used with them in the code (as they're defined) - the difference between startStop1Blk and startStop2Blk are:

```
unsigned char startStop1Blk[6] = {START_STOP, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
unsigned char startStop2Blk[6] = {START_STOP, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0};
```

I am not sure what do you mean by "send only the SCSI EJECT command", but assuming you mean the SCSI command that is responsible for ejection, then eject does issue only them.

According to the [Seagate's SCSI command reference](https://www.seagate.com/files/staticfiles/support/docs/manual/Interface%20manuals/100293068j.pdf), START STOP UNIT is the proper command to handle ejection. Excerpt below:

[image: SCSI command reference excerpt]

Comment: From your description and the STMicro.com code fragment, if the last command from Ubuntu is startStop2Blk, then, even if my code is too slow to see the previous states, the last state set should be the EJECT state.  All I can think of is that the response from the STM32 based device for allowRmBlk or startStop1Blk were never seen by Ubuntu and so the process to eventually send startStop2Blk sometimes does not complete.  Any other thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: My objective was to access the eject feature of Linux & STMicro.com's USB drivers. Thank you for your description @kishkovert however it does not change what I am seeing. The STMicro.com USB driver does store the eject every time I send it from Linux. But masks it with a UNLOCKED or LOCKED state almost immediately. Maybe it is a different part of the Linux OS that is issuing other SCSI commands.  Since I can't rewrite the STMicro.com USB drivers and can not switch to a Win10 host, I think I will use the UMOUNT as a signal to switch my device from USB/MSC to USB/CDC.